# How do i track clicks using facebook pixels?

Tags: facebook, analytics, tracking

I've been re-reading this page and it just seems so vague on how to help me. I have a newsletter button I am trying to track clicks on through facebook pixels but facebooks documentation and lack of proper testing is frustrating me.

Here is the documentation I am reading
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-pixel/events-advanced-use-cases/v2.8

If I read this correctly, to track a single button I have to install code in three different sections? They don't specify the sections either, so I'm assuming they go in the order they displayed it (viewContent goes in the header, button id goes in the body of the page, and the final fbq tracking goes in the footer).

If anyone has a more simple approach to this or can explain this in a better way I would greatly appreciate it. Adding code in three different sections and creating multiple heads just to track different things on different pages seems like a lot more work than I need to be doing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: For testing purposes, I suggest you install the Facebook Pixel Helper Chrome extension. And where f.e. the code to embed the script and fire the basic page view goes, is explained in the “Using the Pixel” section.

Comment: I've been using the Facebook Pixel Helper and its been useful, but still leaves some questions. Example - it says my newsletter conversion isn't working, but I'm seeing conversions when I check the analytics. Thats fine, I can get by with that, but I have custom events that are showing up as conversions but not showing information grabbed from the page (product name, product price for example). We may be looking in the wrong spot for it, or I'm told it may not be showing due to the type of ad being run. This is my first time doing all this, thank you